# Записать условие, которое является истинным, когда только одно из чисел X, Y и Z кратно пяти

Tags: java

> Записать условие, которое является истинным, когда только одно из чисел X, Y и Z кратно пяти.
>   При этом нельзя использовать операторы +-*/  и операторов сравнения не должно быть больше 3х.

Как это сделать?

Comment: А почему вдруг «нельзя использовать операторы +-*/ и операторов сравнения не должно быть больше 3х»? Это практическая проблема или учебное задание?

Comment: Учебное задание.

Comment: @Dagmar а со сдвигом битов не рассматривали задачу?

Comment: Рассматриваю.Именно этим сейчас и занимаюсь,но все равно не могу понять.

Comment: @Dagmar А можно вводить промежуточные переменные?

Comment: К сожалению нет.

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводиться к завершению задач за учащихся. Приведите пример вашей реализации и задайте вопрос с описанием конкретных проблем.

Answer (score 1):

Если разрешается вводить дополнительные переменные для хранения промежуточных результатов, то условие может быть выражено следующим образом

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int x = 5, y = 6, z = 7;
        boolean a = x % 5 == 0, b = y % 5 == 0, c = z % 5 == 0;
        boolean result = !( a && b && c ) && ( a ^ b ^ c );

        System.out.println( result );

        x = 5; y = 5; z = 7;
        a = x % 5 == 0; b = y % 5 == 0; c = z % 5 == 0;
        result = !( a && b && c ) && ( a ^ b ^ c );

        System.out.println( result );

        x = 5; y = 5; z = 5;
        a = x % 5 == 0; b = y % 5 == 0; c = z % 5 == 0;
        result = !( a && b && c ) && ( a ^ b ^ c );

        System.out.println( result );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {


    int x = 9;
    int y = 15;
    int z = 6;
    /* не используем сравнения и арифметические операции в А, В, С,
     * они только чтобы формула не была длинной
     * Остаток от деления может быть 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, то есть
     * 000
     * 001
     * 010
     * 011
     * 100
     * Сдвигаем биты до 2 разрядов, складываем по ИЛИ и умножаем по маске 1
     * Результат будет равен 1, если остаток не равен 0
     *
     */
    int A = ((x % 5)|((x % 5) >> 1)|((x % 5) >> 2)) & 1;
    int B = ((y % 5)|((y % 5) >> 1)|((y % 5) >> 2)) & 1;
    int C = ((z % 5)|((z % 5) >> 1)|((z % 5) >> 2)) & 1;
    System.out.println(A + " " + B + " " + C);
    /* Комбинации, устраивающие нас
     *  A B C
     *  0 1 1
     *  1 0 1
     *  1 1 0
     *
     */

    int result = (~A & B & C) | (A & ~B & C) | (A & B & ~C);

    System.out.println(result == 1);

}

  // второе решение
  static boolean test(int x, int y, int z) {
    int[][] m = {
            { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 2, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 4, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
    };
    int res = m[0][Math.abs(x) % 5] | m[1][Math.abs(y) % 5] | m[2][Math.abs(z) % 5];

    return ( ( res == 1 ) || ( res == 2 ) || ( res == 4) );
}
```

[источник](http://www.cyberforum.ru/java-j2se/thread1794033.html)